# ASP.NET MVC3 Entity Framework - Data Retrieval

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, poco

I'm developing a report tool for my boss using ASP.NET MVC3 and the Entity Framework. I'm using a POCO model and DBContext to retrieve the data from our database and create the data layer. When I created some sample data it was simple: 2 tables with a small number of columns, and it worked liked a charm. Now I am trying to test my application in our test environment, which is where the issue has arisen.

The database that I am working with has 137 tables, but I only need data from two of the tables. I've emulated the two tables I need the data from and set up my application accordingly, but no dice. So my question is do I have to create a class for each table, even though my application is using only 2 of the tables from the database? Also, I have Read-Only privileges in this environment. Which should be fine because my application is simply selecting data, not manipulating it.

**Update**

The error I'm receiving is this:

EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled by user code.
  An error occured while executing the command definition.

Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name

The column name is the PK that I have for the other table I'm joining with.

Comment: 'but no dice' - can you expand?

Comment: Are you getting error messages? Blank data? What exactly is happening that's causing it not to work?

Comment: what is stopping your app from working in the test environment ? Are you getting any errors, please mention them.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the error I'm receiving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You need to either create a class or generate classes for each table in your database.  With entity framework the Database must match your DbContext classes.  You'll want to generate your classes as you've already created your database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx

Comment: No you don't. I'm working on a project now where there's tables in the database that don't exist in EF and it works fine. (Note this is using Database first - I don't know about Code First)

Comment: @CorrugatedAir With code first your database has to match your DataContext

Comment: Ah, ok. OP didn't specify if he was using Code First or not, just that he has POCO objects. If he's using Code First, switching to database first might make sense for him.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the clarification guys. I'm still quite new to all this and working out the kinks. I'll check out the Database First approach. Appreciate the guidance so much!